# iOS Certificate "Push Notification" option is grayed out

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

My "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production)" certificate is about to expire on Nov 6. 
I created a new certificate (for the matter of this question I'll only focus on the production one, though it's the same issue) and tried testing it on my server and it didn't work. 
I then decided to revoke the certificate and create a new one but now - this option is greyed out.
It was already greyed out after I created the new certificate and I figured If I revoke it, the system will allow me to create a new one.
(The old certificate which expires Nov 6 is still active, I don't want to revoke it as the server currently uses that for production push notifications).

Does anyone know why this option is greyed out? How can I create a new push certificate now?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you want to create a new certificate delete the old one and try. Better to create new certificate once it expire.

Comment: Thanks, but (a) the old certificate is not yet expired and I don't want to risk it by revoking it and then not have any push notifications. (b) I was able to create a new one while the old one was existing, only then did this option turned grey... so how do I know that it will turn "enabled" if I revoke the old one...

Answer (score 2):

Push notification certificates are actually created from the App ID page:

- Go to 'Identifiers' -> 'App IDs'
- Select the app you need to update the certificate for and select 'Edit'
- Scroll down to 'Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificates'. You should see a 'Create Certificate...' button

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem as well. We only had a single active production certificate, so we weren't at the limit of 2.

Even though we had an unexpired certificate that was working in production, the App ID associated with the certificate showed Push Notifications as disabled. We re-enabled it, but the Create Certificate button stayed disabled.

Suspecting yet another Member Center bug, I created a new, fake App ID and checked the box to enable Push Notifications for the new App ID. This kicked something inside Member Center, because the Create Certificate button for the other (real) App ID became enabled, along with the radio buttons from the screenshot in the question.

Virtual percussive maintenance?